# if statement in django

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I'm doing tests with django on my pc, if I run the code without else the if statement is true and r1 variable is right.

```
def trovapernome(request, aggregatore, nome):
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/%s.xml" % (aggregatore))
    richiesta = url.read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(richiesta)
    iterator = tree.getiterator("location")
    t = get_template('prova.xml')           
    for name in tree.iter('name'):
        if name.text.lower() == nome.lower():
            c = Context({'id' : name.text})
            r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype='application/xml')
            return r1
```

otherwise this code:

```
def trovapernome(request, aggregatore, nome):
    url = urllib.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/%s.xml" % (aggregatore))
    richiesta = url.read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(richiesta)
    iterator = tree.getiterator("location")
    t = get_template('prova.xml')           
    for name in tree.iter('name'):
        if name.text.lower() == nome.lower():
            c = Context({'id' : name.text})
            r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype='application/xml')
        else:  r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(Context({'id' : 'prova'})), mimetype='application/xml')
    return r1
```

return always the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping in the first code block as the `return` isn't indented correctly.

```
for name in tree.iter('name'):
    if name.text.lower() == nome.lower():
        c = Context({'id' : name.text})
        r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype='application/xml')
        return r1
 # move return indentation to match here, i.e after the for loop completes
```

See how the `return` is matched in your second block when using `else`

```
for name in tree.iter('name'):
    if name.text.lower() == nome.lower():
        c = Context({'id' : name.text})
        r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype='application/xml')
    else:  r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(Context({'id' : 'prova'})), mimetype='application/xml')
return r1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over multiple elements in the tree. In your first version you are returning immediately when processing the first element. In the second version you only return after processing *all* elements in the tree.

Either return from within the loop or determine what needs to be done with the multiple matches:

```
for name in tree.iter('name'):
    if name.text.lower() == nome.lower():
        c = Context({'id' : name.text})
        r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype='application/xml')
    else:  r1 = HttpResponse(t.render(Context({'id' : 'prova'})), mimetype='application/xml')
    return r1  # return the *first* match.
```